# State not updating after setting state

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a contact form, and attempting to setState for each field, then pass that value to an email form.

When I console.log, I'm not getting any output. What am I doing wrong here?

Should I be using useEffect? From what I understand, useEffect is called whenever I set state, so I shouldn't need to. Is there something else I'm missing or doing wrong?

```
import style from "../styles/Contact.module.css";
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Contact() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [subject, setSubject] = useState('')
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})

    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Submit')

    const [showSuccessMessage, setShowSuccessMessage] = useState(false)
    const [showFailureMessage, setShowFailureMessage] = useState(false)

    const handleValidation = () => {
        let tempErrors = {}
        let isValid = true

        setName(document.getElementById('name').value)
        setEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)
        setSubject(document.getElementById('subject').value)
        setMessage(document.getElementById('message').value)

        console.log(name, email, subject, message)
        if (name.length <= 0) {
            tempErrors['name'] = true
            isValid = false
        }
        if (email.length) {
            tempErrors['email'] = true
            isValid = false
        }
        if (subject.length) {
            tempErrors['subject'] = true
            isValid = false
        }
        if (message.length <= 0) {
            tempErrors['message'] = true
            isValid = false
        }

        setErrors({ ...tempErrors })
        console.log('errors', errors)
        return isValid
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        let isValidForm = handleValidation()
        if (isValidForm) {
            setButtonText('Sending')

            const res = await fetch('/api/sendgrid', {
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email,
                    name: name,
                    subject: subject,
                    message: message
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                method: 'POST',
            })

            const { error } = await res.json()
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                setShowSuccessMessage(false)
                setShowFailureMessage('Error, please complete all sections')
                setButtonText('Submit')
                console.log('success is ', showSuccessMessage)
                console.log('failure is ', showFailureMessage)
                return
            }
            setShowSuccessMessage('Contact form submitted')
            setShowFailureMessage(false)
            console.log('success is ', showSuccessMessage)
            console.log('failure is ', showFailureMessage)
            setButtonText('Send')
        }
        console.log(name, email, subject, message)
    }
    return (
        <div className={style.container}>
            <h1 className={style.title}>Get in Touch</h1>
            <form className={style.form}>
                <input className={style.inputS} type="text" placeholder="Name" id='name' />
                <input className={style.inputS} type="text" placeholder="Phone" id='phone' />
                <input className={style.inputL} type="text" placeholder="Email" id='email' />
                <input className={style.inputL} type="text" placeholder="Subject" id='subject' />
                <textarea
                    className={style.textArea}
                    type="text"
                    rows={6}
                    placeholder="Message"
                    id='message'
                />
                <button className={style.button} onClick={handleSubmit}
                >{buttonText}
                </button>
                <p className='error'  >
                    {showSuccessMessage}
                    {showFailureMessage}
                    'test'
                </p>

            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: you mean these lines are not working  ?    console.log('success is ', showSuccessMessage)
                console.log('failure is ', showFailureMessage)

Answer (score 0):

Set state is an asynchronous operation, so log the state after setting it, will log the old value.

If you want to sure that the value has been setten correctly, you need to use setState.

```
        setShowSuccessMessage('Contact form submitted')
        setShowFailureMessage(false)
        setShowSuccessMessage(prev => {
              console.log(prev)
              return prev
        })// log the 'Contact form submitted'
        setShowFailureMessage(prev => {
              console.log(prev)
              return prev
        })// log false
```

And setting state, in this case, will not make the component re-render as you return the same value.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really understand. Isn't that what I'm doing already? Do you mean I need to only console.log it in an arrow function within the success message? Because I'm not as concerned about the console.log statement as I am making sure that the form at the bottom displays the correct error or success message. But as of now, it's always blank indefinitely.

Comment: Somehow it works by changing onChange on the form to log the result directly instead of calling handleChange. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that setXxx methods are async. If you click submit 10 times fast enough, you will see different results.

You have two options:

1. not preferred: If you don't use 'controlled' input (you are not using it now - in input elements, you are not using things like 'value={name}'). then you don't need the state at all.
2. Use controlled input. You can check document on reactjs org.
   Simply put,
   useState
   on the input tag, add `value={name} onChange={changeHandler}`,
   in `changHandler`, setState
   in `formSubmit`, use the value in state

There is a section on forms on this excellent tutorial:
[Bob Ziroll free React Course](https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact/react-forms-intro-co2774b5e9623a1cad018bc49)

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense and I understand now. Though after adding the value and onChange attributes to the form, I still don't see the success or error message at the bottom. I appreciate the help though, but do you know why I'm still not able to update the paragraph tag at the bottom of my form?

Comment: This is my updated code.
https://gist.github.com/TheNomadicAspie/27cbc7d88983abf42fb36288796e96e9

Comment: Somehow it works by changing onChange on the form to log the result directly instead of calling handleChange. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using react so you need to set data and use those data after that i have updated your code it should work for you. i.e. you need to set value in onChange function as below:-

```
import style from "../styles/Contact.module.css";
import React, { useState } from 'react'
const style = {};
export default function Contact() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [subject, setSubject] = useState('')
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})

    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Submit')

    const [showSuccessMessage, setShowSuccessMessage] = useState(false)
    const [showFailureMessage, setShowFailureMessage] = useState(false)

    const handleValidation = () => {
        let tempErrors = {}
        let isValid = true

        console.log(name, email, subject, message)
        if (name.length <= 0) {
            tempErrors['name'] = true
            isValid = false
        }
        if (email.length) {
            tempErrors['email'] = true
            isValid = false
        }
        if (subject.length) {
            tempErrors['subject'] = true
            isValid = false
        }
        if (message.length <= 0) {
            tempErrors['message'] = true
            isValid = false
        }

        setErrors({ ...tempErrors })
        console.log('errors', errors)
        return isValid
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        let isValidForm = handleValidation()
        if (isValidForm) {
            setButtonText('Sending')

            const res = await fetch('/api/sendgrid', {
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email,
                    name: name,
                    subject: subject,
                    message: message
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                method: 'POST',
            })

            const { error } = await res.json()
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                setShowSuccessMessage(false)
                setShowFailureMessage('Error, please complete all sections')
                setButtonText('Submit')
                console.log('success is ', showSuccessMessage)
                console.log('failure is ', showFailureMessage)
                return
            }
            setShowSuccessMessage('Contact form submitted')
            setShowFailureMessage(false)
            console.log('success is ', showSuccessMessage)
            console.log('failure is ', showFailureMessage)
            setButtonText('Send')
        }
        console.log(name, email, subject, message)
    }
    return (
        <div className={style.container}>
            <h1 className={style.title}>Get in Touch</h1>
            <form className={style.form}>
                <input className={style.inputS} type="text" placeholder="Name" id='name' onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                <input className={style.inputS} type="text" placeholder="Phone" id='phone' />
                <input className={style.inputL} type="text" placeholder="Email" id='email' onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <input className={style.inputL} type="text" placeholder="Subject" id='subject' onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)} />
                <textarea
                    className={style.textArea}
                    type="text"
                    rows={6}
                    placeholder="Message"
                    id='message'
                    onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button className={style.button} onClick={handleSubmit}
                >{buttonText}
                </button>
                <p className='error'  >
                    {showSuccessMessage}
                    {showFailureMessage}
                    'test'
                </p>

            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And if you want same for phone you can also set data for the same and use after that.